# How would one find the PID of a browser extension running?

Tags: browser, plugins, process

Its very clear on how to use ps -ax on a Mac to get the running processes, and grepping for the browser. That being said, I also know that browser extensions generally run on a different process from browser for security reasons... I've attempted to use ps -ax | grep Chrome to find the extension processes but I can't find it. Am I missing something?

Comment: `ps -ax | grep 'Google Chrome Helper' | grep "extension-process"`


Should work. You can also go to "Chrome->Options->More Tools->Task Manager" to get the exact PID of your installed extension

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful. You can put this as an answer and I'll award you the points. Thanks again!

Comment: thanks!  Added it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ps -ax | grep 'Google Chrome Helper' | grep "extension-process"`

This should work. You can also go to "Chrome->Options->More Tools->Task Manager" to get the exact PID of your installed extension.

Comment: Thanks! Super helpful.